# How can I dynamically look up key in cocoapods-keys?

Tags: swift, security

I have some secure variables like `clientSecretStage` and `clientSecretProd`.

I want to iterate through my known keys, without the env suffix, to then populate variables during runtime. My code is like this:

```
let secureKeyValues = LiveKeys();
let secureKeys: [String] = [
    "clientSecret",
    "code",
];

let env = 'Prod'; // this would be from config

let clientSecret = secureKeyValues["\(secureKey)\(env)"];
```

On compile, I get `Type 'LiveKeys' has no subscript members`, although 
`print(secureKeyValues.codeProd);` works just fine.

Comment: You are using `[` and `]` to access the value, that's subscripting. That's automatically done with array with index, and dictionary with key. if `LiveKeys()` doesn't implement subscript, you can't use `[` and `]` as such. You can't do `let myInt = 21; let myVar = myInt[1]`, no?

Comment: @Larme that seems about right. I wasn't sure if I was missing anything here. Maybe I'll fork and add that feature in the future. I'm about a week into using Swift so not quite there yet ;) Probably could make this an answer so I can mark question solved with a "No, there is no how" ;)

Comment: More info there: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Subscripts.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible due to the library not supporting that syntax.